# Configure MySQL Stored Procedure with only INT variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I have configured this procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_news
(IN news_id INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT title, body, datetime FROM News
  WHERE id = news_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And I have this PHP Code:

```
$news_id = $_GET["id"];
$dbConnection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","identidad_digital_db");
$sql = "CALL get_news($news_id)";
$result = $dbConnection->query($sql);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count==0){
    header( 'Location: id_not_found.html' );
}
$m = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

I thought that my procedure will fix SQL Injection. However, vulnerability still working. "id" must be only an integer. By this way, the basic "7' and '1'='2" injection works.

Why it does not works? How can I configure correctly my procedure? I read the documentation and some examples but I don't know how to do it.

**UPDATE**

I'am triying with regex but It also does not works:

```
BEGIN
    IF news_id IS NOT NULL AND news_id RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'
    THEN
      SELECT title, body, datetime FROM News
      WHERE id = news_id;
    END IF;
END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CAST for this:

```
IF CAST(news_id AS UNSIGNED) > 0 THEN
   ...
END IF;
```

However, I think you should do this in php:

```
if(isset($news_id) && is_numeric($news_id)){
     ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, both solutions are what I want. Thanks! It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

I configure news_id as varchar(20). Obviously, in my mind these values were int types but they come from a PHP form, so they are strings. By the way, if it helps someone, this is what I got finally:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_news //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_news
(IN news_id VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  IF news_id IS NOT NULL AND news_id REGEXP '^[1-9]+$' THEN
    SELECT id, title, body, datetime FROM News
    WHERE id = news_id;
  END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```